# Android Studio - White Bar Across Top

Tags: android, xml, webview, android-actionbar

So I just built an app but across the top is a white bar. I believe its the ActionBar but every attempt to change the color does not work. Any idea on how to remove it or change its color? Thanks.[image]

Activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small.Inverse" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/LoadingText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:text="@string/loading_txt"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:backgroundTint="#243313"
        app:rippleColor="#FFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


</resources>
```

styles.xml(v21)

```
<resources>>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

LogCat:

```
03-18 20:16:20.495 17416-17416/org.communionchapelefca.ccsatx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: org.communionchapelefca.ccsatx, PID: 17416
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.communionchapelefca.ccsatx/org.communionchapel.ccsatx.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172)
                                                                                    at org.communionchapel.ccsatx.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172) 
                                                                                    at org.communionchapel.ccsatx.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172) 
                                                                                    at org.communionchapel.ccsatx.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
                                                                                    at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:34)
                                                                                    at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:110)
                                                                                    at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:104)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172) 
                                                                                    at org.communionchapel.ccsatx.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: is on an activity or fragment? @Greg Williams

Comment: never mind i just saw its an activity. go on your manifest and define app theme under main activity. should be something like this.  android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"

Comment: that did not work, it still shows the white bar across the top

Comment: i see did you try the answer i posted and it did not work?

Comment: @Salvatory Baya added the LogCat output

I assumed its an ActionBar; how can I confirm if its an ActionBar or StatusBar?

Comment: I can confirm its the status bar. can see the battery and cell tower indicator when zooming in. My answer didnt solve your problem?

Comment: did you try using a hex instead of @android:color/background_dark?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is in your styles v-21 file

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Change this line

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

change '@android:color/transparent' to some other color

Comment: didnt work, it crashed the app. i tried both '@android:color/primary_text_dark` and `@android:color/background_dark`

Comment: you can mark my answer as 'accepted' by click on the 'tick' beside the answer :) glad i could help you. Another thing- whatever color you use for the status bar may not be used in older versions of android so do test your app on api<21

Comment: I configured the colour to:  @color/colorPrimaryDark which gave the same look as my main activity which has the nav_draw model.